# Flutter Error : .../packages/flutter_tools: No such file or directory - install

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to install flutter correctly on linux , many time I get this Errors:

```
/home/beit/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 24: cd: /home/beit/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
```

I saw some solutions for this problem such as deleting the "bin" folder, run pub repair, and stuff
but they could not solve the problem

I just want to start Flutter

note: I download the Dart SDK package many times, and use "flutter doctor"

I use the following command line for installation (as Linux install doc in flutter.dev):

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

Comment: Can you please add information about the distro and the method you used to install flutter

Comment: I use following code: `sudo snap install flutter --classic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution , use manually install to solve this problem
1- first delete your previous version of flutter use :

```
snap remove flutter
```

2- next , download flutter SDK from here:
[please download stable channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)

3- follow this link: [if you use Linux](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually)

4 - do the optionally step:

```
flutter precache
```

done! , you can use "flutter doctor" command line to check other things.